# JavaFX drag and drop to the 'white space' of a javafx.scene.Group

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag'n'drop to a group containing several shapes and lines. Point is, the DragEvent is detected - but only on the children of the group.

Simple snippet:

```
addEventFilter(DragEvent.ANY, dragEvent -> {
    dragEvent.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
    System.out.println(dragEvent.getEventType());
    dragEvent.consume();
});
```

Is there a way that the DragEvent is detected 'everywhere' inside the bounds of the group, especially the white space or do I have to manage the children with something different than a group, and what could that be?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) for `Group` reads "A Group will take on the collective bounds of its children and is not directly resizable.", which implies it has no "white space" - it is only a logical grouping. So yes, perhaps you should look into using a different container (maybe a `StackPane`?)

Comment: Thanks, I changed to `Pane` so no code changes had to be made. 
I only had to disable d'n'd support for every kind of children so that only the white space accepts the `DragEvent`.